# TestFlight Won't Send Notification

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

1. I’ve uploaded a new beta, version 6, build 1, of an active app.
    
   I have two different emails set up as internal test accounts, in
   case one works where the other won’t.
2. The uploaded beta is showing in the Internal Testing Screen, radio
   button checked next to "Version 6 — Build 1 — Testing — Expires in
   60 days"
3. My Tester IDs are showing in the "Internal Testers" list below.

By all accounts, it should be working, but it does not. I read one post here where the solution was to toggle the TestFlight testing option on and off and a notification would automatically be generated and sent, but there is no place to do that. I’ve searched everywhere. Why can’t there just be a simple “Send Notification” option somewhere?

Cayce

Answer (score 2):

Just remove and add those internal testers again

Step 1: Go to ITC -> My Apps -> App -> Testflight -> Internal Testing

Step 2 (Remove tester information): Edit -> Select internal tester apple ids -> Remove -> Save

Step 3 (Add tester information again): Click on "+" button and add the internal testers you removed in step 2 again.

This will notify user.